# Mocha - should I initialize stubs directly in the describe() block or inside before()

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon

I need a reference to the stub variables so that I can `reset()` and `restore()` on `afterEach()` and `after()` callbacks.

My initial approach is to define the stubs in the `describe()` block so that the variable can be accessed in the callbacks:

```
describe('my SUT', () => {
  const myStub = sinon.stub(myModule, 'itsMethod');

  after(() => {
    myStub.restore();
  });
});
```

However, I'm wondering whether there are benefits (that I yet don't know about) of using the `before()` callback for initialization:

```
describe('my SUT', () => {
  let myStub = null;

  before(() => {
    myStub = sinon.stub(myModule, 'itsMethod');
  });

  after(() => {
    myStub.restore();
  });
});
```

Is there any benefits of using the second approach (maybe something like more output if somethings goes wrong, etc)?

If so, it feels wrong having lots of `let myVar = null` lying around at the beginning, any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `beforeEach` and `afterEach` in place of `before` and `after` to create and clean up most stubs and spies.

Of course, this depends on the situation-- and it doesn't make a difference if you only have one `it` in your `describe` block. But in the event that you do, it's usually better for each test to have its own fresh copy of the stub. That way you can write assertions against the stub's state (its call count, call args, etc) in each test that don't rely on the other tests.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an issue with the execution order.

The thing is that the body of a describe block is executed before any `before`, `after` and `it` blocks.

Say we have an api with 2 methods and we are stubbing them in 2 different `describe`'s:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

const api = {
    getFoo() { console.log('executed Foo') },
    getBar() { console.log('executed Bar') }
};

describe('spec 1', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(api, 'getFoo').callsFake(() => {console.log('executed Foo stub')});
    console.log('Replaced getFoo with a stub');

    it('test 1', () => {
        console.log('running test 1');

        // We expect a stub to be executed here.
        api.getFoo();
        // We expect an actual method here.
        // But IN FACT we are executing a stub from the next describe block.
        api.getBar();
    });

    after(() => stub.restore());
});

describe('spec 2', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(api, 'getBar').callsFake(() => {console.log('executed Bar stub')});
    console.log('Replaced getBar with a stub');

    it('test 2', () => { console.log('running test 2'); });

    after(() => stub.restore());
});

/* Replaced getFoo with a stub
Replaced getBar with a stub
spec 1
running test 1
executed Foo stub
executed Bar stub */
```

As you can see we have both stubs applied before the first test even started. This is an undeterministic behaviour.

To solve any issues and have the code clean you could use [sinon sandboxes](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.3.0/sandbox/) + `before` and `after` blocks (or beforeEach/afterEach).

Everything is going to be stubbed/unstubbed in the right order + one stub can contain unlimited amount of stubs/spies/etc and can be restored in on shot.

```js
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe('spec 1', () => {
    before(() => {
        sandbox.stub(api, 'getFoo').callsFake(() => { console.log('executed getFoo stub'); });
    });

    after(() => sandbox.restore());

    it('test 1', () => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

They also give a nice example in the docs.